# Calling REST Service from Jquery With Tomee1.7.1

Tags: java, jquery, rest

I am new to Web Services. I am doing one demo app where I am calling REST Service on a button click from jquery. But Its not calling. I searched a lot but helpless.I am using Apache Tomee1.7.1. 
Here I have written two classes :
1) UserService -> which extends `javax.ws.rs.core.Application` class.

```
@ApplicationPath("App")
public class UserService extends Application{

    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        System.out.println("in getclasses method...");
        Set<Class<?>> set = new HashSet<Class<?>>();
        set.add(MyService.class);
        set.add(User.class);
        set.add(UserDao.class);
        return set;
    }


}
```

2) MyService -> which contain REST service

```
@Path("users")
public class MyService {

    UserDao uDao = new UserDao();
    User u = null;

    @Path("save")
    @POST
    @Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    public JSONObject saveUser(User u){
        System.out.println("in save");
        if(u != null){
            JSONObject juser = new JSONObject();
            User user = uDao.saveUser(u);
            /*juser.put("accnumber", user.getAccNumber());
            juser.put("username", user.getUserName());
            juser.put("bankname", user.getBankName());
            juser.put("depositamt", user.getAmount());
            juser.put("regdate", user.getDate());*/

            juser.put("user", user);
            return juser;
        }
        else
            return null;

    }

}
```

This service is expected to call java method which saves user form data to database.

3) Calling Service as below in jquery :

```
 $("#btnSave").click(function(){

         alert("save clicked...");
         $.ajax({

             type: "POST",
             url : "http://localhost:8080/App/users/save", 
            datatype : "json",
            contenttype: "application/json",
            Accept : "application/json",
            data : formToJson(),
         success : function(data){
             alert("data :"+data);
             //alert("user added!");
         },
         error : function(data){
            //alert("data="+data);
             alert("failed! "+e);
         }

         });
    });
```

In calling url, App is name specified in `@ApplicationPath`, users is name specified in `@Path` and save in `@Path` for REST Method.

When I execute demo,everything works fine but when i click save button I guess Rest method is not being called, rest all jquery alerts n methods are working.

Can anyone help me to call Service? As I am not getting where I am going wrong,any suggestions are welcome.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have added App name to the URL,but still its same, saying Failed!NOT FOUND. Its not finding my Service.

Comment: My App name is AppDup , So my updated URL is "http://localhost:8080/AppDup/App/users/save".

Comment: Its also not getting a match to the name specified in @ApplicationPath. I am creating class extending Application class as I don't have anything in web.xml except welcome file.

Comment: Yes. Its AppDup only.

Comment: No,not any exceptions but when i click save button,it executes everything and gives Failed error showing NOT Found in firebug console. In the REST Service classes I have sysouts,but it doesnt print any of them. So I am sure service is not being called.Not getting what is going wrong.Do you think I am going right way about Creating Applcation class?

Comment: Ok. Once again thanks for your response.

Comment: Yeah,updated contentType also.

Comment: Hey I copied it. I will execute it and will give you update. Thanks a lot.